# Sonarqube Coverage is 0.0 for a multi-module java project

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, devops, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

Sonarqube Coverage is 0.0% even after adding Jacoco plugin and other sonar properties as shown below :

```
<sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.tests>src/test/java</sonar.tests>
        <sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
        <sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <sonar.exclusions>src/test/**</sonar.exclusions>
        <sonar.java.binaries>=**/target/classes</sonar.java.binaries>


<plugins>                            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I've compiled the src code and added sonar.java.binaries property, Have i missed out anything or please suggest any workaround ? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the command you use to execute the sonar goal?

Comment: This may help
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/

Comment: @Haim Raman, Thanks, there was an issue with the write up for jacoco plugin, fixed it and that doc was helpful and sonar.jacoco.reportPaths is deprecated.

Comment: SonarQube is displaying the coverage data that is provided.You need to check the coverage file provided.